LogPlot and % preventing PlotStyle from being correctly applied
I'm running into a problem that does not seem to be documented anywhere (or at least, Google does not find it). I will give a MWE highlighting it, which I hope clearly shows the issue.
The situation
I have multiple functions I want to plot. To do so with lin-lin scales, I used a code such as
{x^2,
 x^3}
Plot[{%}, {x, 0, 0.04}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]

Which is equivalent to
Plot[{x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 0.04}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]

As can be seen:

The problem
I now want to use a logarithmic y-axis. To do so, I replace Plotby LogPlot. In my original code, this gives something like
{x^2,
 x^3}
LogPlot[{%}, {x, 0, 0.04}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]

And this should be equivalent to the other way of writing it (that I don't want to use)
LogPlot[{x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 0.04}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]

However, it turns out to not be the case, as the first option breaks the PlotStyle by only applying the last parameter:

So, how can I use LogPlotwith both the % and a PlotStyle?
Thanks !
Complementary information
I run Mathematica 13.3.1.0 Student Edition on a MAC OS X ARM (64-bit) platform, the laptop being a 2020 M1 MacBook Air 13''.
I do not want to not use the % and rely on the second working option.

MMA 14.0 Works for me.

It looks like this has been changed ("fixed") from 13.3 to 14.0.

Workaround in 13.3: {x^2, x^3}; LogPlot[Evaluate@%, {x, 0, 0.04}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]

As pointed out by Daniel Huber and Domen in the comments, who I thank here for lack of possibility to mark any of their comments as accepted answer, this faulty behavior isn't present in Mathematica 14.0.
So, the solution is:
Upgrade Mathematica to version 14.0.
(And this was indeed a bug).
